# Why have for-loops with pre-increment the same behaviour as those with post-increment?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, post-increment, pre-increment

It's probably fair to say everyone learns writing for-loops using post-increment:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log(i); // 0..9
}
```

When I swap the post-increment out for a pre-increment, I'd expect the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  console.log(i); // 1..10
}
```

My reasoning: `i` is initialised to `0`; the loop's body will be executed while `i` is less than 10; `i` is incremented to `1` and the loop's body is entered; `i`with value `1` is printed to consele; the loop's condition is evaluated again; etc.

Yet the output is (at least for JavaScript in Chrome) the same as for a post-increment: `0..9`. Why is that? Is the increment executed after the body is run?

Comment: The update happens after the body of the loop runs.

Comment: You need to understand how loops work. What the engine enters the loop it initialises the variable and checks the exit condition. Once it has processed the instructions within the loop it then does the increment, checks the exit condition etc. This is why using pre ore post increment makes no real difference

Comment: @jeff for a post-increment, that was clear. But for a pre-increment, my intuition led me astray. Thanks for explaining, everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last part of the for loop only happens at the **end** of each loop.

So `++i` **and** `i++` do basically the same thing in that case.

---

Order of operations:

```
var i = 0;

while (i < 10) {
   // do stuff
   console.log(i);
   // increment i in your own way
   ++i; // or i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the latter example the sequence of operations is

```
var i = 0; // obviously
if (i < 10) /* proceed */
console.log(i); 
++i;
```

The "++" doesn't say "jump the queue and do the operations in an entirely different order," as you seem to suspect.

Comment: The if check happens **before** the console log.

Answer (score -1):

*Is the increment executed after the body is run?* Yes.

See those semicolons? They mean that they are entirely different expressions.

Take this small example:

```
var i = 0;
if (i<5)
    i++;
console.log(i);
```

and

```
var i = 0;
if (i<5)
    ++i;
console.log(i);
```

**(These examples are not replicating the functionality of a loop.)** You see, you'll get the same answer for both, because just like a `for` loop, they are entirely separate expressions.

Now, if you had:

```
var i = 0;
i += i++;
console.log(i);
```

and

```
var i=0;
i+= ++i;
console.log(i);
```

Ahh, since the operators are being used in the *same* expression, then the one we use matters!

That is basically what is happening. Since they are different expressions, imagine them being run on different lines.

Comment: The increment happens after the console log.

Comment: @Tuvia. Obviously, my examples aren't replicating the loop, they are for demonstration purposes, demonstrating the concept of the fact that a for loop is separated into multiple statements.